# Extracting an icon and app name from an apk file

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, apk

I have a mongodb database with data inserted from the apk manifest. However it only has the package name and the app icon as a resourceID.I would like to access the icon and the actual app name so i can show them on a vuejs webpage.

The icon element is saved like this in the database.

> "icon":"resourceId:0x7f0e0001"

I already found the icon in the apk(***.apk/res/mipmap/), but there are more than 1 png file and some of them aren't even the correct logo of the app.

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: This is a sample of the mongodb document:

```
{ "app":{ "_id":"5c410f0105a2736015420f10", "versionName":"2.73.0", "package":"com.Slack", "platformBuildVersionCode":20009618, "platformBuildVersionName":"2.73.0", "usesPermissions":[ { "name":"android.permission.INTERNET" },... "application":{ "theme":"resourceId:0x7f120141", "label":"resourceId:0x7f1100f2", "icon":"resourceId:0x7f0e0001", "name":"com.Slack.SlackApp", "allowBackup":false, "resizeableActivity":true, ...
```

Comment: post how your mongo document looks like and also post what you want to see as result (using that document)

Comment: (I am assuming you mean the json file describing the mongo document) It is too long for me to post it here. However i can post some parts of it if you think this would help you understand the problem better.
What i want is to find the location of the app name and the icon and extract them from the apk.

Comment: yes please. Also a resulting (look alike) document from the sample document